# Unity: Texture2D ReadPixels for specific Display

Tags: camera, pixel, texture2d, display, unity-game-engine

Unity has had support for multiple display outputs for a while now (up to 8).

With the `ReadPixels` function, you can specify an area to read from, and an origin coordinate. But I cannot **specify a display** number to perform the read on.

I need to be able to read pixels from a specific display (1-8) with a specific area and origin point.

How can I do this, please?

Comment: I think unity3d can read pixels inside its window, I doubt you can maximize a window with the size of 8 displays. Even when maximized it will take only 1 display, you can see what Im talking about if you play Endless Legend, when you start the game the window is centered in the middle between display 1 and 2 and you have to move this window to the desired display and then hit alt+enter in order to maximize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** achieve ReadPixels for a specific screen/display. You have to do the following:

*Before I start, I assume you have a number of cameras which are each rendering to a different display. The cameras must not have a RenderTexture attached to them in order to output to a display.*

Define a function which does the following:

1. Assign the desired camera a temporary RenderTexture
2. Use `RenderTexture.active = *temporary render texture*` to make the currently active rendertexture equal the temporary one you just created
3. Use `ReadPixels` to read in pixels into a temporary `texture2d` using an appropriate `Rect`. This will read from the currently active `RenderTexture`
4. Call `Apply()` on the `texture2d`
5. Set the `RenderTexture.active` and camera `RenderTexture` to `null`

The idea is that ReadPixels works on the currently Active RenderTexture.

The code should look something like this:

```
    outputCam.targetTexture = outputCamRenderTexture;
    RenderTexture.active = outputCamRenderTexture;
    outputCam.Render ();
    tempResidualTex.ReadPixels (screenRect, 0, 0);
    tempResidualTex.Apply ();

    RenderTexture.active = null;
    outputCam.targetTexture = null;
```