# ReadPixels every frame from specific camera Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

I am trying to share my screen, but from a specific camera in Unity. By using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894840/unity-texture2d-readpixels-for-specific-display) of copying from a render texture, my app does not work obviously, since I need to do this every frame.

Is there an approach where I can read the pixels - **every frame** - from a **specific camera** without hurting the performance so badly?

Comment: not sure about it but could be possible that the problem could be on how are you streaming/sharing your image screen, more than the cost of recover image information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was answered on [Agora slack channel](https://agoraiodev.slack.com/archives/CFDG7Q6F6/p1600794381029000?thread_ts=1600339570.241100&cid=CFDG7Q6F6).  Posting verified answer here so others can learn about it:

Your crash may be related to creating the RenderTexture buffer each time with Update() or every frame.  You should reuse a buffering variable instead.  There shouldn't be a performance issue if you handle memory management correctly.